# Do MIPS pseudoinstructions get converted to machine code on a one to one scale?

Tags: mips

As far as I know, regular MIPS instructions are converted to machine code (binary) on a one to one scale. However, I'm curious as to whether pseudoinstructions like la and li are the same way. Would it be fair to say that pseudoinstructions work the same way and are also converted on a one to one scale?

Comment: No. They get converted into one _or more_ actual instructions.

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I did try to use my ide but honestly had no idea what I was reading, though I suspected I was right